# Create map from map

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have class `AB`:

```
class AB{
  private final String a;
  private final String b;

  public AB(String a, String b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  public String getB() {
    return b;
  }

  public String getA() {
    return a;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {...}

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {...}
}
```

Now, I create map `Map<AB,Float> mapWithData` to count how many times in server response we have in stats.log `a` serviceName and `b` servicePort.

We sum it in map `servicesNamePort.merge(new AB(...,...), 1.0f, Float::sum)`

How can I create map from `Map<AB,Float> mapWithData` where key is **b** and value is map of **a as key, and float as value** it means `Map<String **(b)**, Map<String**(a)**,Float>>`

I try to use `Collectors.groupingBy` but I have this answer:

```
Map<String, List<Map.Entry<AB, Float>>> collect = mapWithData.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(abEntry-> abEntry.getKey().getB()));
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point you’ve missed, is that you can specify another `Collector` as second argument to the `groupingBy` collector to specify how to collect the groups:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> collect = mapWithData.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getB(),
                 Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getA(),
                     Collectors.summingDouble(e -> e.getValue()))));
```

This is the closest to you question, you can get, as there is no direct support for `Float`.

But since this number is supposed to be a *count*, I’d rather use `Integer` or `Long` anyway.

If your `mapWithData` was declared as `Map<AB,Long>`, you could use

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> collect = mapWithData.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getB(),
                 Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getA(),
                     Collectors.summingLong(e -> e.getValue()))));
```

---

If it really has to be a `Float` result, you can use

```
Map<String, Map<String, Float>> collect = mapWithData.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getB(),
                 Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getA(),
                     Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                         Collectors.summingDouble(e->e.getValue()), Double::floatValue))));
```